Is possible to do this in Webflux? Call 2 services in parallel and do not wait for the second if a condition is met with the first
I want to call 2 services "a" and "b" and depending on the response of a, wait or not for b.
Something like this:
    public Mono<String> test() {

        Mono<String> monoA = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            try {
                log.info("A Started");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                log.info("A Ended");
                return Math.random() > 0.5 ? "A" : "a";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

        Mono<String> monoB = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            try {
                log.info("B Started");
                Thread.sleep(8000);
                log.info("B Ended");
                return "B";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return monoA.flatMap(a -> {
            Mono<String> result;
            if(a.equals("A")) {
                result = Mono.just(a);
            } else {
                result = monoB;
            }
            return result;
        }).map(response -> {
            long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            return "Returning '" + response + "' in: " + totalTime + " ms";
        });

    }

If monoA = "A" prints:
A Started  
A Ended  
Returning 'A' in: 2032 ms

If monoA = "a" prints:
A Started  
A Ended  
B Started  
B Ended  
Returning 'B' in: 10007 ms

if i use:
Mono.zip(monoA, monoB)
The best and worst case is always 8000ms
I want
if monoA = "A" response in 2000ms  
if monoA = "a" response in 8000ms

Is what I want possible or even right to do?

I believe that to achieve what you want, you need to start execution of monoB unconditionally. Please note .cache() for monoB, it prevents re-execution of monoB.
Full code wrapped in a @ParameterizedTest-annotated method using StepVerifier.
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class MonoTest {
    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MonoTest.class);

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"a", "A"})
    void test(String monoAResult) {
        Mono<String> monoA = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            try {
                log.info("A Started");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                log.info("A Ended");
                return monoAResult;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

        Mono<String> monoB = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            try {
                log.info("B Started");
                Thread.sleep(8000);
                log.info("B Ended");
                return "B";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).cache();

        monoB.subscribe(); // start execution of monoB

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Mono<String> monoResult = monoA.flatMap(it -> "A".equals(it)
                ? Mono.just(it)
                : monoB);

        StepVerifier.create(monoResult).assertNext(response -> {
                    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                    if ("A".equals(monoAResult)) {
                        assertTrue(elapsedTime < 2100, "Execution time exceeded 2100 ms for result 'A'");
                    } else {
                        assertTrue(elapsedTime < 8100, "Execution time exceeded 8100 ms for result 'B'");
                    }
                })
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}


That's a really nice approach to what I was looking for, thanks!
